# PHP Autoloader not loading classes properly?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I have problem with autoloader not loading classes properly. I am not sure if I am doing it right... I am using slim framework.

My `composer.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "robmorgan/phinx": "^0.6.6",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
        "philo/laravel-blade": "3.*"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Cipo\\": ["app/"]
        }
    }
}
```

And my directory structure:

```
app/
    Controllers/
        Console/
            AuthController.php
            UsersController.php
        HomeController.php
    Core/
        AbstractController.php
    router.php
database/
public/
    index.php
vendor/
views/
storage/
composer.json
```

My `router.php` looks like this:

```
$app->get("/", Cipo\Controllers\HomeController::class . ":index");
$app->get("/auth/login", Cipo\Controllers\Console\AuthController::class . ":getLogin");
```

The problem is that `/` works and shows the proper HTML, but `/auth/login` does not work. Here is the error that is thrown:

```
[Tue Jan 31 14:11:37.758803 2017] [:error] [pid 1336] [client 44.44.44.1:54453] Slim Application Error:
Type: RuntimeException
Message: Callable Cipo\\Controllers\\Console\\AuthController does not exist
File: /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php
Line: 62
Trace: #0 /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolverAwareTrait.php(45): Slim\\CallableResolver->resolve('Cipo\\\\Controller...')
#1 /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(333): Slim\\Routable->resolveCallable('Cipo\\\\Controller...')
#2 /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))
#3 /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(316): Slim\\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))
#4 /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(438): Slim\\Route->run(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))
#5 /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))
#6 /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(332): Slim\\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))
#7 /var/www/cipo.me/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(293): Slim\\App->process(Object(Slim\\Http\\Request), Object(Slim\\Http\\Response))
#8 /var/www/cipo.me/public/index.php(45): Slim\\App->run()
#9 {main}
View in rendered output by enabling the "displayErrorDetails" setting.
```

And `AuthController.php` snippet:

```
<?php

namespace Cipo\Controllers\Console;

use PDO;
use Cipo\Core\AbstractController;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;


/**
 * Class AuthController
 * @property \PDO db
 * @property \Philo\Blade\Blade blade
 */
class AuthController extends AbstractController
{
    // ...
    public function getLogin(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $response->getBody()->write($this->blade->view()->make("auth.login")->render());
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious issues. If the route for `/` works, then the autoloader _"should"_ work. Have you checked that you don't have any nasty typo in any file- or folder name? A similar thing have happened to me, at some point. Copy/pasting the name of the controller everywhere helped in that case.

Comment: I've tried `/users` route `$app->get("/users", Cipo\Controllers\Console\UsersController::class . ":index");` and it works, looks like there are some typos :(

Comment: I have figured it out. Problem was my `AuthController` class was in file called `AuthControllers.php` instead of `AuthController.php`

Comment: There you go! You're not the first person that managed to lose your head over a similar mistake. :)